# Alternative to the expression "we are going to"

Tags: expressions

At the moment I'm writing a sort of economical report over Bosch GmbH. That's a group work and I would like to report our data and our analysis in the most clear and straightforward way.
I have an issue though, I found myself writing an awful lot of times the expression "we are going to". Here some examples

- In this section **we are going to** focus on the financial...
- **We are going to** perform a first level analysis of ROE...
- For the short term situation **we are going to** use two different approach...

I don't really like to use the *WE*, but neither I can seem to find a non redundant solution to say the same thing.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always invert the subject, which gives you the opportunity to hide the usage of singular/plural.

- The main focus will be on the financial...
- A first level analysis of ROE will be performed...
- For the short term situation, two different approaches will be used...

It allows you to put the important part of the sentence as the subject, and you (as a bonus) don't get caught up on whether or not to use "we" in those sentences.

**Edit**

For cases where you can't avoid it, e.g. if your company does something differently than others, it's acceptable to use we/our.
In general though, I'd focus on what *will* be done, and not *who* will do it.

Difference in phrasing, which coincidentally also gets rids of your problem.